# Adding a new row into TableLayoutPanel with a click of a button

Tags: vb.net

I have a tablelayoutpanel with 6 columns and 2 rows. The first row contains headings for the columns, the second row contains 2 comboboxes and 4 textboxes.

When the program is running i wish to be able to click on either a button or the plus symbol to create a new row with the 2 comboboxes and 4 textboxes. As seen in the pic

[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmA0Q.png)

Comment: Welcome - add some code of what you have tried thus far

Comment: I recommend you use a `DataGridView` instead.

Comment: If You use a datagridview can you still use combobox for the first 2 columns

Comment: @devN yes you can have combobox in any column and more than one column as well. Also you can create a user control with the controls you need and add this as many times as you would need. You can throw them in a flowlayoutpanel which would keep them nice and ordered for you as well.

Comment: Thanks @Codexer that helped a lot